# morris data not displayed in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, morris.js

I have the following code in my controller...

```
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = new[] {new Entry() {value = 20, year = 2008}, new Entry() {value = 10, year = 2009}};

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public class Entry
    {
        public int year { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
```

And this in my view ..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', function (result) {
             Morris.Line({
                element: 'mysecondchart',
                data: [result],
                xkey: 'year',
                ykeys: ['value'],
                labels: ['Value']
            });
    });
</script>
```

In debug mode I can see the GetData is triggered but no chartis displayed. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action method returns an collection of items and the `result` parameter of your ajax method callback function is an **array** like this

```
[{"year":2008,"value":20},{"year":2009,"value":10}]
```

When you use the expression `[result]` it wraps the existing array to a new array, hence you will get a nested array like this

```
[[{"year":2008,"value":20},{"year":2009,"value":10}]]
```

which is not what the `data` property of `Line` method expects.

So the solution is to replace  `data: [result]`, with  `data: result,`

This should work.

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', function (result) {

     Morris.Line({
        element: 'mysecondchart',
        data: result,
        xkey: 'year',
        ykeys: ['value'],
        labels: ['Value']
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the explenation. It worked fine now :)